# Why current_user_can('edit_comment') always true?

Tags: filters, user-roles

I am always getting `TRUE` for `current_user_can('edit_comment');` on two different installations of WordPress (4.2.2 and 4.2.4) no matter what role the user is. Even when the user is logged out.

I tested this on a clean WP install and got the same result.

Why would this be?

Comment: I tested it on a third WP install, same thing. This makes no sense to me. All these WP instabilities are getting old and makes me wish I was working under a different platform.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how it is singular? Comment, not comments?

This capability is not designed to check if user can edit any arbitrary comment out there. It can only check if user can edit one specific comment and correct way to call it is `current_user_can( 'edit_comment', $comment_id )`.

Unfortunately second argument is missing from `current_user_can()` function signature and it is extremely unobvious that some capabilities must be checked in this fashion.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, thanks for clearing this up. I will give it a try. Do you know if `edit_comment` is a core capability? This is unclear to me; I don't think it is. I read some where that WP checks `edit_posts` capability for comments but I am not sure if they really know what they are saying.

Comment: I don't think there is  more generic capability for this. You might have better luck asking new question with details on what you are trying to achieve and troubles you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I think, to debug this scenario, you should first try following to get all the capabilities for the current user and see whether `edit_comment` actually exists in it or not -

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );

$allcaps = $userdata->allcaps;

$output = print_r( $allcaps, true );   

echo '<pre>' . $output . '</pre>';
```

Also, check if `moderate_comments` suits your requirement instead.

Comment: I checked $capabilities array under the user object and `edit_comment` is not set. @Rarst pointed out that `edit_comment` must be checked along with a `comment id` for this function to work, I will give it a shot soon and return with an update. Thanks for your suggestion!